# how parse this date Wed May 14 2014 11:15:12 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) using d3.format?

Tags: json, function, parsing, d3.js, console

Here is a function to convert a unix datetime to datetime but I still have a problem with parsing the date a specific format . The converted unix date is

((Wed May 14 2014 11:15:12 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time))

apparently I have a problem with the d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %Z").parse;

this is the function

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var _parse = d3.time.format("%a %b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %Z").parse;
  var maybeDateString = timeConverter("\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/");

  console.log(maybeDateString); 

  function timeConverter(maybeDateString){
  maybeDateString= maybeDateString.substring(0, 26);
  maybeDateString= Date(maybeDateString*1000)
  maybeDateString= _parse(maybeDateString);
         return maybeDateString;
}
 console.log(_parse)

 </script>
```

why I can't console.log(_parse)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to do what you're trying to do (you already have the Date object, why try to convert that to a string and then parse it back into a date?).  But, the problem is probably with the way the timezone is being printed, with the long timezone name in brackets.  The parsing function doesn't recognize that (%Z only equates to "-0800").  From the specs: ["If the specified string does not exactly match the associated format specifier, this method returns null."](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse)

Comment: I know that I must match the specifier with the date format. I'm trying to convert the unix format to a date format using the parse function coz d3.js needed like that. The whole idea of changing the format coz I need to visualise it into a line chart ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results you want by using [`d3.time.format.iso`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format_iso) as your date formatting function, and `d3.time.format.iso.parse` as your parsing function.

These use the built in Javascript ISO parsing functions, and so can handle the standard output from Javascript Date functions (including long timezone names).

In contrast, most d3 date parsing functions are very strict -- the input data must match the specified format exactly or else it returns null.  And since the d3 format specifiers have no way of indicating long timezone names or arbitrary strings, your date format was never matching the string version of your Dates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Can I ask you more questions ? Can you please show me an example or even better to show me what changes should I do in my code ? . Again , thank you

Comment: For your simple example code, ` _parse = d3.time.format.iso.parse;` would work.  Beyond that, I am not sure what you need.  If you just want to use a Date object in your d3 code, you already have that at `Date(maybeDateString*1000)`.